# Add brush on top of d3 barchart

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add a brush on top of a barchart in d3. Currently I am using barchart for my example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768

This is the example of the brush that I want to implement: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

I can only find examples where the bush is below the chart and not on the main chart itself. Can anyone explain to me how to put the brush on top of the barchart or point me in the direction of an example that I could follow?

Comment: According to your examples you are using d3 v3 ? If you are not constrained by a version, take a look at version 4 and the [brush module](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush); it comes with some ease comparing the previous brush functionality and there is a few examples using the brush on the whole area (like [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/0d20834e3d5a46138752f86b9b79727e)).

Comment: Hi, do you have a working example of brush on stacked bar chart as per your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Brush & Zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172) example you are referring to, there are following lines:

```
var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

...
  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "zoom")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom);
```

These are specifying positions of the chart area, brush area and zoom area. You can just tweak `margin` and `margin2` values which are specified at the beginning of the script, or explicitly set up a different transformation here.

You need to have `margin.top > margin2.top`, and tweak bottom margins too.